# ViewBinder and disappearing Images

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewbinder

We've gotten it to show the images and hide them when needed but they are Disappearing when i scroll down or up. Anyone every seen this or know its cause? Not sure whats going on but when i scroll its as if it is redetermine if it needs to be displayed and its going with no even though for that date it is yes.

```
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment { 

  ListView listTimeline;
  SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
  TextView txtCreatedAt, txtFertile, txtTemp, txtCervix;
  ImageView imgIntercorse, imgEnergy, imgPregancy, imgMood, imgHeadache, imgPeriod;
  IntentFilter filter;

  static final String[] FROM = { StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE, StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_NOTES, StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE, 
                                 StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE, StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_PERIOD, StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_INTERCORSE,
                                 StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_MOOD, StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_HEADACHE, StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_TEST, 
                                 StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_ENERGY };
    static final int[] TO = { R.id.txtCreatedAt, R.id.txtNote, R.id.txtFertile, 
                              R.id.txtTemp, R.id.imgPeriod, R.id.imgIntercorse,
                              R.id.imgMood, R.id.imgHeadache, R.id.imgPregancy,
                              R.id.imgEnergy};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    }

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
         listTimeline = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listTimeline);

         return view;
     }

     @Override
     public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.setupList();
      }

  @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
  }

  private void setupList() { 
      txtCreatedAt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtCreatedAt);
      txtFertile = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtFertile);
      txtTemp = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtTemp);
      txtCervix = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtCervix);
      imgIntercorse = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgIntercorse);
      imgEnergy = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgEnergy);
      imgPregancy = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgPregancy);
      imgMood = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgMood);
      imgHeadache = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgHeadache);
      imgPeriod = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgPeriod);


      // Get the data
      Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(StatusProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHARTING, null, null , null, StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE + " DESC"); // <3>


      // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
      //as well as the layout information
      adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.history_row, c, FROM, TO);
      adapter.setViewBinder(new CustomViewBinder());

      // Assign adapter to ListView
      listTimeline.setAdapter(adapter);


  }



  private class CustomViewBinder implements ViewBinder {

      private Date parseDate(String date) {
            SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date dateObj = new Date();

            try {
                dateObj = curFormater.parse(date);
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return dateObj;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

             if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE)) {
                 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                 String date = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                 Date dateObj = parseDate(date);

                 String formatedDate = format.format(dateObj);

                 TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                 tv.setText(formatedDate);
                 return true;
             }



            if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_PERIOD)) {
                // If the column is IS_STAR then we use custom view.
                String is_period = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                if (is_period != null) {
                    if (is_period.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                        // set the visibility of the view to GONE
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_INTERCORSE)) {
                // If the column is IS_STAR then we use custom view.
                String is_intercorse = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                if (is_intercorse != null) {
                    if (is_intercorse.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                        // set the visibility of the view to GONE
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_MOOD)) {
                // If the column is IS_STAR then we use custom view.
                String is_mood = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                if (is_mood != null) {
                    if (is_mood.equalsIgnoreCase("no") ) {
                        // set the visibility of the view to GONE
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_HEADACHE)) {
                // If the column is IS_STAR then we use custom view.
                String is_headache = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                if (is_headache != null) {
                    if (is_headache.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                        // set the visibility of the view to GONE
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_TEST)) {
                // If the column is IS_STAR then we use custom view.
                String is_test = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                if (is_test != null) {
                    if (is_test.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                    // set the visibility of the view to GONE
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_ENERGY)) {
                // If the column is IS_STAR then we use custom view.
                String is_energy = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                if (is_energy != null) {
                    if (is_energy.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
                        // set the visibility of the view to GONE
                        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }


            // For others, we simply return false so that the default binding
            // happens.
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

XML 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent">

  <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" 
        android:text="@string/title_history"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

  <!-- <1> -->
  <ListView 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/listTimeline"
        android:background="#6000" />


</LinearLayout>
```

XML2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblFertile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtCreatedAt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCreatedAt"
        android:text="@string/lblFertile"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTemp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblFertile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblFertile"
        android:text="@string/lblTemp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTemp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblTemp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblTemp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtFertile"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:text="@string/NA" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCervix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblCervix"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblCervix"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblCervix"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:text="@string/NA" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFertile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblFertile"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblFertile"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblFertile"
        android:paddingLeft="5sp"
        android:text="@string/NA" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCreatedAt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"
        android:text="@string/defDate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblCervix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtFertile"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtCreatedAt"
        android:text="@string/lblCervix"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgIntercorse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pregnancy_history"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPregancy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pregnancy_history" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPeriod"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/period_history" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHeadache"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pregnancy_history"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"  />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pregnancy_history" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEnergy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pregnancy_history" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/NA" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't prefix you questions titles with `Android`, the tag at the bottom is more than enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in a `ViewBinder` you need to always provide a revert option for the view changes to handle a possible recycled row. I don't know which are your images so here is an example:

```
if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_PERIOD)) {
            // If the column is IS_STAR then we use custom view.
            String is_period = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            if (is_period != null) {
                if (is_period.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
                    // set the visibility of the view to GONE
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    // bring the view to its default state which I'm assuming is being visible
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```